# MySQL query that will leave out results that were repeated at least and most times

Tags: mysql

I need a MySQL query to get the results where there will not be mostly and least repeated values.

What that means?

If this MySQL query:

```
 SELECT Ocjena,COUNT(*) FROM ocjenjivanje GROUP BY Ocjena;
```

returns:

[image]

I need query which will give me the next results:

```
Ocjena 
1
3
5
```

Thanks

Comment: Surely 1, 3, 4 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT Ocjena, COUNT(*) AS c FROM ocjenjivanje GROUP BY Ocjena) AS o
INNER JOIN (SELECT Min(c) AS l, Max(c) AS h FROM  (SELECT Ocjena, COUNT(*) AS c FROM ocjenjivanje GROUP BY Ocjena)) AS m
ON o.c <> m.l AND o.c <> m.h
----OR
--ON o.c NOT IN(m.l, m.h)
```

or you can use this query:

```
SELECT Ocjena, c
FROM
( SELECT o.*, @min:=IF(@min > o.c, o.c, @min) AS l, @max:=IF(@max < o.c, o.c, @max) AS h
  FROM (SELECT Ocjena, COUNT(*) AS c FROM ocjenjivanje GROUP BY Ocjena) AS o
  , (select @max:=0, @min:=32000) AS m) AS x
WHERE c NOT IN(l, h)
```

Comment: Thanks.

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON o.c <> m.l AND o.c <> m.h
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4

Comment: I will accept your answer due to your effort but that doesn't give me the expected result. Here is how I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

I don't know can I make it better to look more professional or to be faster, or something like that.

```
SELECT *    FROM     `Ocjenjivanje`  WHERE Ocjena != (    SELECT Ocjena 
FROM     `Ocjenjivanje`
GROUP BY `Ocjena`
ORDER BY `Ocjena` DESC
LIMIT 1) AND OCjena != ( SELECT Ocjena
FROM     `Ocjenjivanje`
GROUP BY `Ocjena`
ORDER BY `Ocjena` ASC
LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY `Ocjena`
```

Comment: but this query return Ocjena {2, 3, 4}, not the "mostly and least repeated values"...

Answer (score 0):

you can get result like this from query posted in your answer (but it isn't return rows expected in question), using one of this query:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT Ocjena, COUNT(*) AS c FROM ocjenjivanje GROUP BY Ocjena) AS o
INNER JOIN (SELECT Min(Ocjena) AS l, Max(Ocjena) AS h FROM ocjenjivanje) AS m
ON o.Ocjena <> m.l AND o.Ocjena <> m.h

SELECT Ocjena, COUNT(*) AS c 
FROM ocjenjivanje AS o
WHERE o.Ocjena <> (SELECT Min(Ocjena) FROM ocjenjivanje)
AND o.Ocjena <> (SELECT Max(Ocjena) FROM ocjenjivanje)
GROUP BY Ocjena

SELECT Ocjena, COUNT(*) AS c 
FROM ocjenjivanje AS o
WHERE o.Ocjena NOT IN (SELECT Min(Ocjena) FROM ocjenjivanje UNION SELECT Max(Ocjena) FROM ocjenjivanje)
GROUP BY Ocjena
```